# Добавление столбцов в WPF DataGrid Binding

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding

Есть модель, у неё есть свойства.
В `DataGrid` я через `Binding` привязываю некоторые свойства. Но также в эту же таблицу мне нужно вставить столбцы с данными, которые я вычисляю в событии `DataGrid LoadingRow`. Подскажите как это сделать. Вариант с `DataTable` не подходит.
Так выглядит `Binding` полей таблицы (именно закомментированные поля нужно заполнить данными):

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn  MaxWidth="200" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NamePurpose }" Header="Наименование цели"/>
      <!-- <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Progress, StringFormat=\{0:0.00\}}" Header="Прогресс(%)"/> -->
      <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}}" Header="Дата начала"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}}" Header="Дата окончания"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding NeedeedSum, StringFormat=\{0:0.00\}}" Header="Необходимая сумма"/>
      <!--<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding HaveSum, StringFormat=\{0:0.00\}}" Header="Собранная сумма"/>-->
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Что-то не совсем ясна проблема... Ведь если брать канонический MVVM, то вполне можно связать ViewModel с событием `LoadingRow`?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский к сожалению, в проекте не используется MVVM )) Поэтому интересует как добавить данные в закоментированые поля. Не обязательно в событии `LoadingRow`. Другой способ тоже приемлем.

Comment: Вы же привязываете список объектов? Что мешает извлечь его в событии LoadingRow и в объектах проставить нужные свойства? Они бы автоматом показались. Конечно, если есть эти поля в объектах или есть возможность их туда внести. Почти mvvm получится:)